# SQLite3 open file problems

Tags: sqlite

I'm using GTK+ and SQLite as a front end for a small database program, and I cannot get SQLite to properly detect file type on open.  Not matter what is opened, it returns SQLITE_OK.

I tried `sqlite3_open` and `sqlite3_open_v2`, the problem still persists.  The output is always the same, regardless of what filetype is opened:

```
/home/shawn/Programming/languagedb/lang.db
0 6304656
good
/home/shawn/Programming/languagedb/Makefile
0 6304656
good
```

And here is the related code:

```
void OpenDialog()
{
    GtkWidget *WinOpen;

    WinOpen = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Open Database",GTK_WINDOW(WinOpen),GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,GTK_STOCK_CANCEL,GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,GTK_STOCK_OPEN,GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,NULL);

    if(GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT == gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(WinOpen)))
    {
        char *filename;
        filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(WinOpen));
        printf("%s\n",filename);

        db = NULL;
        rc = sqlite3_open_v2(filename,&db,SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY,NULL);

        printf("%i %i\n",rc,&db);

        if(SQLITE_OK == rc && NULL != db)
        {
            printf("good\n");
        }

        sqlite3_close(db);
    }

    gtk_widget_destroy(WinOpen);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I also said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877439/sqlite3open-problems-checking-if-a-file-is-a-sqlite3-database/1877496#1877496) you need to execute a non-`pragma` statement against the open database handle before SQLite tries to read, and then verify the file's contents.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure what that meant, so I'll do some more research.